# Why home Air Conditioning AC compressor insulated

Tags: hvac

Compressor is hot due to gas compression, and the gas then cooled in condenser. AC installed in tropical climate. Why compressor have insulation barrier?[image: AC outdoor units, compressor]

Comment: Stop ambient heat entering...? Or noise reduction?

Comment: Ambient heat cannot entering since compressor temperature must be higher than ambient. This is also happened to be R-32 refrigerant (higher condenser temperature).

Comment: But heat can go back to the environment which you are trying to cool... As pointed out by Olin...

Comment: You mean, heat go to outlet of condenser. That's can make sense, but should be the outlet condenser tubing to be insulated. I'm thinking why don't we air cooled the compressor also. This discussion might lead to some system improvements.

Comment: No, that unit is trying to cool the space it is in.. if the heat from the compressor gets back into that space then it is wasted work, so i sulate the compressor so the heat is taken away by the fluid to the condensor...

Comment: Wait, in AC split, the compressor is outside of the room. While indoor units don't have compressor. I don't get your saying. About insulate the compressor so the heat is taken away by fluid to condenser - I think it is better for compressor work if the gas is intermediate-cooled (like multistage compression with its interstage coolers).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77042/discussion-between-rainerj-and-solar-mike).

Comment: The picture of the unit you provided is what I have been commenting on....

Comment: Please provide make and model of condenser unit.

Comment: @Phill Sweet, make & model is irrelevant for this answer since other make & model may have same insulation.

Answer (score 2):

Knowledgeable service man said it was for noise reduction.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but some possibilities:

To reduce noise.

To reduce heat exchange in places other than where it is wanted/used.

Comment: Please elaborate #2 ?